# Putting sprites over background in a game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm having trouble loading a sprite into a game. I have the background done, but the sprite doesn't seem to be on the background. I want to assume you put it in the main constructor, but I don't think it will work.

```
package MyGamePKG;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class GameJFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private int x,y,x_vel,y_vel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GameJFrame frame = new GameJFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GameJFrame() {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 720, 520);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    GameJPanel Jpanel = new GameJPanel();
    Jpanel.setBounds(0, 0, 720, 480);
    contentPane.add(Jpanel);
    Jpanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GameJFrame.class.getResource("/Resources/gamemap.png")));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 720, 480);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);




}
}
```

The JPanel class

```
package MyGamePKG;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;

public class GameJPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

private int frameRate = 30;
private int x=0;
private int y=460;
private int x_vel, y_vel;
private Image map;
private Image character;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public GameJPanel() {
    character = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/sprite-concepts.png")).getImage();
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    Timer timer = new Timer(30, this);      
    timer.start();


}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
    this.setOpaque(false);
    myDrawBoxOvalsandRect(x,y,100,g2d);
    //myDrawArc(x+25,y+40,50,50,550,170,g2d);
} // paintComponent
public void myDrawBoxOvalsandRect( int x, int y, int scale, Graphics my_g)
{
    my_g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    my_g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15); //face


}
public void myDrawArc(int x, int y, int height, int width, int angle1, int angle2, Graphics my_g)
{
    my_g.setColor(Color.red);
    my_g.drawArc(x, y, 50, 50, 550, 170); //happy face      
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int c = e.getKeyCode();

    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x_vel = -2;
        y_vel = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        x_vel = 0;
        y_vel = -2;
    }
    if( c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x_vel = 2;
        y_vel = 0;
    }
    if( c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        x_vel = 0;
        y_vel = 2;
    }
    repaint();

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x_vel = 0;
    y_vel = 0;
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(x < 0)
    {
        x_vel = 0;
        x = 0;
    }
    if(x > 720)
    {
        x_vel = 0;
        x = 720;
    }
    if(y < 0)
    {
        y_vel = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    if(y > 480)
    {
        y_vel = 0;
        y = 480;
    }
    x = x + x_vel;
    y = y + y_vel;
    repaint();

}


}
```

Comment: Given the fact that the background image sits on top of the sprite pane,there's nothing you can do. You should really use a single component that renders the entire scene, building up the background, middle ground and foreground

Comment: I tested it with a small circle but I commented it out in the code and the circle went on top of the background.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a number of things...

1. It's possible that the z-ordering of the components is rendering the background over the foreground components
2. The reliance on `null` layouts means that it's possible the window borders are taking up more space then you are allowing for, covering up portions of the content.

Don't rely on a null layout and guess work.  Each platform/Look and Feel has different requirements when it comes to the frame border (amongst other things).  Instead, you should consider...

- Overriding `getPreferredSize` to provide better sizing hints
- Use an `OverlayLayout` manager
- Use `JFrame#pack` to pack the frame around the content instead of using `setBounds`

Consider painting the entire game state using a single `paintComponent` method, this would mean rendering the background, middleground and foreground within `GameJPanel`'s `paintComponent`.

The benefit of this, is you gain complete control over the z-ordering process.

You should consider using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over using `KeyListener` as it does not suffer from the same focus related issues and provides you with finer control over determining the level of focus that the component will raise key events